# Phonegap does not work on the device but runs on the emulator

Tags: android, cordova, permissions, emulation, mobile-devices

The application runs on the emulator but does not work on your phone.

permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

config:

```
<access origin="*" />


    code:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<!--
Customize this policy to fit your own app's needs. For more guidance, see:
https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist/blob/master/README.md#content-security-policy
Some notes:
* gap: is required only on iOS (when using UIWebView) and is needed for JS->native communication
* https://ssl.gstatic.com is required only on Android and is needed for TalkBack to function properly
* Disables use of inline scripts in order to mitigate risk of XSS vulnerabilities. To change this:
* Enable inline JS: add 'unsafe-inline' to default-src
-->
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
<meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
<title>Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>
<img src="domain/templates/MediaLoad/adminLoadFiles/e0e8338bb31f8f301cc2332016f05d32.jpg" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

connetc plugin`s:

whitelist
pushbots

Thank you in advance for your help! :)

Comment: What error when your app open in device?

Comment: Post javascript code.